# Hover on slideToggle (2 divs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm facing a problem with my javascript/jquery.

I have a div at the bottom of my screen, when I hover on it, I want that a div is coming up and stay there when i'm with my mouse at it. When I go out of the box then it should collapse again. My html:

```
<div id="footer">
            <div id="howitworksBtn">
                How it works
            </div>

            <div id="howitworksContent">
                Second box
            </div>
        </div>
```

And my Javascript, It's not working yet so please help!

```
$("#howitworksBtn").hover(function () {
    $(this).parent().find("#howitworksContent").stop().slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

EDIT:

My css:

```
#howitworksBtn {
    width: 220px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: gray;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

#howitworksContent {
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: helvetica;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "NOt Working"..? Are you getting any error messages in console?

Comment: No, I just don't get it working ;)

Comment: It's working fine on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CTQ2q/).

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want the content to scroll or want the whole contnet div to move up?

Comment: Uh, what I want is that it comes from the bottom and then you are automatic at the "Content" div. So, in the "second box" on your fiddle. But then it slide again.

Comment: Edit: put the css in the question. Then you guys should understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is surprisingly very simple..  :)

```
$("#howitworksBtn").parent().hover(function () {
        $(this).find("#howitworksContent").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hover takes 2 functions as parameters:

[.hover() jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$("#howitworksBtn").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).parent().find("#howitworksContent").stop().slideToggle("slow");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).parent().find("#howitworksContent").stop().slideToggle("slow");
    }
);
```

Comment: Don't stay open if you're at the second box